# Chrome Extension local .gif not displaying

Tags: html, google-chrome-extension

I am writing a chrome extension and injecting an image into the page. When I do this in my content script:

```
var loading_img = document.createElement('img');
var imgURL = chrome.extension.getURL("images/icon.png");
loading_img.src = imgURL;
document.body.appendChild(loading_img);
```

and I see my image as expected.

However, when I try to load a .gif image. Then the image doesn't load:

```
var loading_img = document.createElement('img');
var imgURL = chrome.extension.getURL("images/loading.gif");
loading_img.src = imgURL;
document.body.appendChild(loading_img);
```

I get a one of these:

[image: img not found icon]

However, if I *inspect element* and grab the `src` of the image element, `chrome-extension://ofdomghnlpcpemcbmidihnbmojhnkhhf/images/loading.gif`, and paste it into my browser window, then I can see the image just fine. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, `chrome.extension.getURL` has been deprecated since Chrome 58, use [`chrome.runtime.getURL`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#method-getURL) instead.

And second, you need to add your gif to `web_accessible_resources` inside your `manifest.json` like so:

```
"web_accessible_resources": ["images/loading.gif"],
```

Comment: Thank you. I had `"web_accessible_resources": ["images/*.png"],` Duh. No wonder my png's would load but my .gif wouldn't... I need to get more sleep.